# Find duplicate inside an array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, robo3t

I have a Mongo Collection called Users and structured  structured like this

```
{
    _id: '1234aaa',
    profile: {
        Organizations: [A,B,C,A,B,A]
    }
},
{
    _id: '1234bbb',
    profile: {
        Organizations: [A,B,C]
    }

},
{
    _id: '1234ccc',
    profile: {
        Organizations: [A,B,C,C]
    }

}
```

How do I return a list of all the documents in my collection ONLY if they have a duplicate value under profile.organizations. 
The expected result would be:

```
DupesUsers: {
    {
        User: '1234aaa,
        Dupes: [A,B]
    },
    {
        User: '1234ccc,
        Dupes: [C]
    },
}
```

I've tried using Aggreagte:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$profile.organizations"},
  { $project: {_id: '$_id', org: '$profile.organizations'} },
  { $group: {
        _id: null, 
        occurances: {$push: {'org': '$_id', count: '$count'}}
        }
   }
);
```

but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not far off just some minor tweaks needed:

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$profile.organizations"
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "dup" : "$profile.organizations", 
                    "id" : "$_id"
                }, 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "count" : {
                    "$gt" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                 _id: "$_id.id",
                 Dupes: {$push: "$_id.dup"}
            }
        }
    ], 
);
```

Comment: This is close but no cigar :D, this gives me the middle one aswell since it has more than two orgs...

Comment: could you clarify?, I've re-simulated my query with those 3 documents and i get the desired result, the match is on the count of the grouped field so what your describing should not happen

Answer (score 1):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DqR8ubGatfs)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "Dupes": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$setUnion": ["$profile.Organizations"] },
        "as": "s",
        "cond": {
          "$gt": [
            { "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$profile.Organizations",
                "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this", "$$s"] }
              }
            }},
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```